# Installing Ubuntu 18.04 cuDNN on Ubuntu 19.10

Tags: ubuntu, nvidia, cudnn

I would like to install NVidia cuDNN on my Ubuntu 19.10 machine.  The [cuDNN download page](https://developer.nvidia.com/rdp/cudnn-download) only offers Ubuntu 18.04.  Can I just go ahead and install an 18.04 package on 19.10 and assume that it will probably work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That way round is most probably works. Installing package made for newer distro is much more likely to be runnable on older distro (depending on features of newer libraries or newer kernel). Of course that should be only done if necessary.

Comment: Thanks.  None of the NVidia distros are prepackaged for 19.10 but when I built my machine I used 19.10 because it is new and shiny.

Comment: Yes I'm also at that version. Strongly waiting for 20.04 need some updated packages that made it into Debian 11 but not in 19.10.. it's missing some 3rd party packages that were available in 19.04 so I use that version. I think some vendors will only support LTS while most will include next release in their build environment for next release of their software, while other might do so only if package would not run at all otherwise.